# Do any poskim discourage Bible study?

Tags: halacha, tanach, oral-torah

The Torah is traditionally seen as being comprised of a Written Torah - the Bible - and an Oral Torah - all other traditions that comprise the covenant between God and Israel. For millennia Jewish scholarship has been heavily weighted towards Oral Torah and only a minority of the sages devoted great effort to studying Written Torah.

Some poskim say that the Bible is simply too easily understood in a heterodox fashion by the immature and therefore it is unsuitable for children. This is the view of Zemah Gaon [as reported by Abraham Zacuto](https://books.google.ca/books?id=eFOmovW0zCMC&lpg=PA124&ots=VCzTCFSbMz&hl=iw&pg=PA124#v=onepage&q&f=false) and some later poskim adopted a similar (if not quite identical) position - e.g., [Nathan ben Jehiel](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HeArukh%2C_Letter_Heh.17?vhe=Sefer_HeArukh,_Lublin_1883&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) and [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Berakhot.28b.7?lang=he). Obviously, this is difficult to reconcile with [the view that requires a father to teach his sons the Bible](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kiddushin.30a.3?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he).

Other poskim say that the Bible should only be studied between the ages of five and ten and the rest of a man's years ought to spent exclusively on Oral Torah. This is the view of [Maharsha](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Bava_Metzia.33a.4?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he). This view is difficult to reconcile with [Joshua ben Hananiah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kiddushin.30a.10?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)'s recommendation that a man split his study time between Bible, Mishnah and Talmud.

Theoretically, a third view is possible that considers the Bible unsuitable for *both* children and adults. One wonders if such an stringent view exists in the poskim?

Comment: How would you understand shnayim mikrah in this context?

Comment: Also worth noting @Moshe that there are mekoros that note that the age brackets set as per pikei avos for chumash, mishnah and gemoro etc are no longer relevant....

Comment: See Abarbanel on that mishna; it doesn't appear in any manuscript and was never quoted until the 15th century. Giving an age for gemara study before the gemara had been written is also an internal difficulty. So this age guide is actually Rishonic.

Comment: No no, contesting the "pirkei avos" that @Dov cited. I have no reason to doubt Zacuto.

Comment: Avot 5:21: "At five years of age the study of Scripture; at ten the study of Mishnah;...
at fifteen the study of Talmud;"

Comment: Yes @MauriceMizrahi - there are several sources that point to the fact that this is no longer relevant due to yeridas hadoros - earlier generations knew how to derive all the hidden concepts from the letters etc. and so they spent a long time on Chumash study to perfect this limmud. Now we no longer have this skill we can start Mishna and Gemara study earlier.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi That mishna literally does not exist and was invented in the late Rishonic period, as Abarbanel says. It did not exist in any version of the mishna produced before about 1450, by which point similar lists had already appeared in mainstream Rishonic works of halakha. You can look at the manuscripts for yourself! Or ask yourself: how could a Mishnaic-era text mandate an age for learning gemara?

Comment: @user25970 even if the Gemara wasn’t written down, it was verbally transmitted. It existed in the times of the Mishnah. To explain the discrepancies and contradictions, even though it was only written down later. There’s no reason to claim a Mishnah doesn’t exist.

Comment: @user25970 -- I agree with Chatzkel.  Some* attribute this saying to Tanna Shmuel HaKatan, not Yehuda ben Tema, but so what?  Why does it make it any less authoritative?   *https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5.21?lang=bi&with=Tosafot%20Yom%20Tov&lang2=en

Comment: Does the Maharsha apply to most of us?  I thought he was talking about people who have a proper background in Tanach by age ten.  Unfortunately, I didn't and still don't.

Comment: "There's no reason to claim a Mishnah doesn't exist" the reason is that the mishnah does not exist. As I said before, you can check the manuscripts yourself, and the rishonim. It does not exist. In the earliest versions (15th century) it has no given author, which, when placed after the preceding mishna, implied Yehuda ben Tema. As to @Chatzkel's argument, I don't doubt that the information existed but there is no Mishnaic-era reference to the gemara as a body.

Comment: This is part of the Torah. How could anyone say that you cannot study it? I think it's no accident that neither of your examples say that, just try to sort out the best timing.

Comment: A disciple of ibn Aderet writes that Bible study gets no reward whatsoever. If this is understood literally then at least one rabbi does not consider the Bible a real part of the Torah, whose study is compensated handsomely.

Comment: One of the most baffling things about the question is this. Go open a random page of Nach. Pretty much anywhere you land you'll find some words Hashem is speaking directly at us, in a tone that is almost desperate, as if to say "I implore you to take these words to heart, and get the message of what I am trying to say here so that you will correct your ways and become what I expect of you". It's beyond imagining that there would be some later opinion that comes along and _discourages_ one from learning Tanach (this is not to say this isn't a good question!)

Comment: In Biblical times, prophets were sometimes harassed and sometimes even killed in cold blood, suggesting that not everyone thinks the word of God ought to be attended to.

Comment: @Dov it is possible that shnayim mikra proponents limit the denigration of Bible study to the prophets and the writings. Some modern poskim adopt such a view explicitly.

Comment: The Maharsha does not say that person would stop studying at 5 or 10, he says "At the beginning of a person's study, he should study the written Torah, Mishnah, and Talmud. However, when he grows in wisdom and does not need to study the written Torah, he should turn to the study of Mishnah and Talmud according to the breadth of his heart and return his attention to the written Torah at times as needed. " So if a person was 20 or 40 or 100, but still needed to study Written Torah, per the Maharsha, he would continue to study written Torah.

Comment: @BID that quotation sounds more like Maimonides. Maharsha uses Maimonides to explain the anti-Bible dictum העוסקין במקרא מדה ואינה מדה and the upshot from Maharsha is that the Bible is exclusively studied (ideally) between the ages of 5-10

Comment: @MosheWise I don't read it as him going against the Rambam, i read it as him synergizing the sources, ie "However, as one grows in wisdom and no longer needs to study the written Torah, he should turn to the study of Mishnah and Talmud according to the breadth of his heart and return his attention to the written Torah at times as needed. Therefore, the passage [pierki avot 5:21] states that the measure for studying the written Torah is not a constant measure, but rather a limited time during a person's youth, until the age of ten."  (cont.)

Comment: (cont) so the period associated with Torah study is 5-10, but still it is according to individual needs and level per the Rambam, and you would still consult the Torah at intervals. But i could be reading it wrong or misunderstanding your position.

Comment: My position is not relevant as I am not a posek. Maharsha's bottom line view is that ideally the Bible is studied in childhood and then put away.

Answer (score 5):

While you linked to the Maharsha, he quotes and channels the [Rambam in Mishneh Torah](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/910973/jewish/Talmud-Torah-Chapter-One.htm), who says:

> בַּמֶּה דְּבָרִים אֲמוּרִים בִּתְחִלַּת תַּלְמוּדוֹ שֶׁל אָדָם אֲבָל כְּשֶׁיַּגְדִּיל בְּחָכְמָה וְלֹא יְהֵא צָרִיךְ לֹא לִלְמֹד תּוֹרָה שֶׁבִּכְתָב וְלֹא לַעֲסֹק תָּמִיד בַּתּוֹרָה שֶׁבְּעַל פֶּה יִקְרָא בְּעִתִּים מְזֻמָּנִים תּוֹרָה שֶׁבִּכְתָב וְדִבְרֵי הַשְּׁמוּעָה כְּדֵי שֶׁלֹּא יִשְׁכַּח דָּבָר מִדִּבְרֵי דִּינֵי תּוֹרָה וְיִפְנֶה כָּל יָמָיו לַגְּמָרָא בִּלְבַד לְפִי רֹחַב שֶׁיֵּשׁ בְּלִבּוֹ וְיִשּׁוּב דַּעְתּוֹ:

> The above applies in the early stages of a person's study. However, when a person increases his knowledge and does not have the need to read the Written Law, or occupy himself with the Oral Law constantly, he should study the Written Law and the oral tradition at designated times. Thus, he will not forget any aspect of the laws of the Torah. [However,] he should focus his attention on the Gemara alone for his entire life, according to his ambition and his ability to concentrate.

This isn't forbidding study of Scripture, just recommending a particular focus and emphasis. And even such a person should learn Scripture at particular set times, so that he doesn't forget.

Zemah Gaon's [approach](https://jbqnew.jewishbible.org/jbq-past-issues/2016/442-april-june-2016/can-one-criticize-biblical-heroes/) was a reaction to Karaism. Rather, as children, they are to focus more on the midrashic interpretations and stories, and only delve into such things as peshat by learning bare pesukim and thinking about peshat interpretations later in life.

Combining these approaches doesn't seem logically consistent, though that wouldn't preclude a posek somewhere, somehow, from possibly disagreeing. Aside from leining thrice in shul, and shnayim mikra ve'echad targum, the Rambam approach is that one need not learn Scripture after that point because one already internalized it and has no need for it. And the Zemach Gaon approach is that it is indeed Talmud Torah, but delay it. So once one delayed it in childhood, why would one not learn it -- indeed be **forbidden** from learning it (as Rambam and Maharsha never ever said) in adulthood?

Comment: The word גמרא is a censor's substitution for Maimonides' תלמוד. See https://mechon-mamre.org/i/1301.htm

Comment: Zemah Gaon does not say his explanation of הגיון is rooted in anti-Karaite polemic. One wonders if there is any evidence for seeing his interpretation as mere polemic. Many later commentators adopted his view even in regions where Karaism was rare or non-existent so perhaps the polemic explanation is not really correct.

Comment: In the linked article, this explanation is attributed to R. Yehoshua Rice, Hi Sichati (Alon Shvut: Maggid Press, 2013), p. 36. No one said "polemic", which would indicate perhapss that he didn't mean it. Rather, a reaction to the realities of his present day. Karaism was 9th century, as was Tzemach Gaon. He does say (according to your link) that the issue is שהן נוטין למינות. Later commentators needn't shed light on him. Please link to them so we can consider their words in context.

Comment: If Rashi, yoter midai means to exceedingly focus on it, not to prohibit teaching it. If the Aruch, מפתרון פסוק כצורתו means not to teach it to them literally, not to prohibit studying it. Regardless, both are translating one opinion in the gemara in its context, rather than giving a pesak halacha. Then, how to balance one gemara with another gemara is a commonly arising issue, where one either says that different Tannaim / Amoraim have different approaches, or that they are meant to modify / mitigate one another. On reflection, yes, Tzamach Gaon too...